# jQuery plugin query mySQL database for data

Tags: mysql, json, jquery-plugins

OK, my apologies for this 'simple' question but I've forgotten ....

Have a jQuery plugin where the data comes from a mySQL db.  How do I pass the object via the plugin options - see said simple :)

e.g.
`jQuery('elementName').pluginName({
  elements_per_page:8,
  data: // A GET function to the mySQL for the data
})`

the php  query is simple like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tableName';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$data = json_encode($row);
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $data . ')';
```

I have just totally forgotten how to pass the object directly into the plugin.  Oviously there is something like this but 'how':

```
jQuery.getJSON( "functions.php&callback=?",function(data){
  return data;
})
```

Plugin options a bit like this

```
var settings = $.extend({
  elements_per_page:5,
  data:data,
}, options );
```

Thanks in advance

//// EDIT ////

If I do it by calling the data first e.g.:

```
jQuery.getJSON("functions.php?table=table",function(data){
  return pluginTest(data)
})
```

AND THEN call the plugin from the function pluginTest(data) like this

```
function pluginTest(data){
  jQuery('elementName').pluginName({
    elements_per_page:8,
    data:data
  })
}
```

Obviously works (well it does :) ) BUT what I really want/would like to do is call the data from within the plugin NOT call the plugin from the data as per this edit so it is more like this

```
jQuery('elementName').pluginName({
  elements_per_page:8,
  data: // A GET function to the mySQL for the data
})`
```

//// END EDIT ////

Comment: See [jQuery.Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Sloan - tnks, obviously get the data via the GET call, but I cannot get the object back into the plugin data object hence question - all I get via console log id the actual function and not the data (object)

Comment: The success function in the ajax call is where you handle the returned data. Also, the data returned should be consistant (ie. all JSON). No idea why your php has the $_GET['callback'] before the JSON data. Your getJSON function call returns data? To what? It isn't "called" by anything, so the return is meaningless.

Comment: Look at the jQuery AJAX examples. Your code doesn't resemble any example I've seen.